# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task

Tags: javascript, react-native, macos, installation

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/easywork/Desktop/react-native/notifi01/android/local.properties'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
React-native error
while npx react-natice run-android

I'm new to react tried building my first app.
tried building I found the error and and fix it.
I am posting this question to answer it myself and to remember the response.

Answer (score 0):

Define ANDROID_HOME Environment Variable:
On macOS/Linux:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
```

s2- go to .android , create a  local.properties File:
type it and save.

```
**sdk.dir=/Users/easywork/Library/Android/sdk**
```

Rebuild Your Project:
Try rebuilding your project by running the Gradle build task again. In your project directory, execute:

```
**./gradlew clean**


**./gradlew assembleDebug**
```

**DONE**

Additionally
Check Android Studio Configuration:
If you are using Android Studio for your React Native project, make sure the SDK path is correctly configured within Android Studio as well. You can go to Android Studio's preferences or settings and navigate to "Appearance & Behavior" > "System Settings" > "Android SDK" and ensure that the correct SDK path is set there.